# Keras Conditional GAN does not train well

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am attempting to build a Conditional GAN model based on jacob's code on keras-dcgan (https://github.com/jacobgil/keras-dcgan).

The model architecture I assumed is the following picture:
[image: the model architecture]

original paper:
http://cs231n.stanford.edu/reports/2015/pdfs/jgauthie_final_report.pdf

For generator, I insert the condition (the condition is a bunch of one-hot vectors in this case) by first concatenating it with noise, then feed the concatenation through the generator.

For discriminator, I insert the condition by concatenating with a flattened layer in the middle of the model.

My code runs, but it generates some random graph instead of specific numbers. Which step is wrong?  Did I not insert the condition appropriately?

My result after running approximately 5500 iterations:
[image: My result after running approximately 5500 iterations]

Code:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, merge
from keras.layers import Reshape, concatenate
from keras.layers.core import Activation
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import UpSampling2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Flatten
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import argparse
import math
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')

# based on the labels below, we create a flattened array with 10 one-hot-vectors, and call it y_prime
labels = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9])

def dense_to_one_hot(labels_dense, num_classes=10):
    """Convert class labels from scalars to one-hot vectors."""
    num_labels = labels_dense.shape[0]
    index_offset = np.arange(num_labels) * num_classes
    labels_one_hot = np.zeros((num_labels, num_classes))
    labels_one_hot.flat[index_offset + labels_dense.ravel()] = 1
    return labels_one_hot

# y_dim is the number of labels in one hot vector form, hence its 10
# y_prime is a 100*10 matrix, and len(y_p) = 100. Note that len(y_prime) must equate to batch_size for the matrices to be properly concatenated
# Also y_dim=10, which is the size of any one-hot vector
y_p = dense_to_one_hot(labels)
y_size = len(y_p)
y_dim = len(y_p[0])


#g_inputs is the input for generator
#auxiliary_input is the condition
#d_inputs is the input for discriminator
g_inputs = (Input(shape=(100,), dtype='float32'))
auxiliary_input = (Input(shape=(y_dim,), dtype='float32'))
d_inputs = (Input(shape=(1,28,28), dtype='float32'))

def generator_model():
    T = concatenate([g_inputs,auxiliary_input])
    T = (Dense(1024))(T)
    T = (Dense(128*7*7))(T)
    T = (BatchNormalization())(T)
    T = (Activation('tanh'))(T)
    T = (Reshape((128, 7, 7), input_shape=(128*7*7,)))(T)
    T = (UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))(T)
    T = (Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, border_mode='same'))(T)
    T = (BatchNormalization())(T)
    T = (Activation('tanh'))(T)
    T = (UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))(T)
    T = (Convolution2D(1, 5, 5, border_mode='same'))(T)
    T = (BatchNormalization())(T)
    T = (Activation('tanh'))(T)
    model = Model(input=[g_inputs,auxiliary_input], output=T)
    return model

def discriminator_model():
    T = (Convolution2D(filters= 64, kernel_size= (5,5), padding='same'))(d_inputs)
    T = (BatchNormalization())(T)
    T = (Activation('tanh'))(T)
    T = (MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))(T)
    T = (Convolution2D(128, 5, 5))(T)
    T = (BatchNormalization())(T)
    T = (Activation('tanh'))(T)
    T = (MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))(T)
    T = (Flatten())(T)
    T = concatenate([T, auxiliary_input])
    T = (Dense(1024))(T)
    T = (Activation('tanh'))(T)
    T = (Dense(1))(T)
    T = (Activation('sigmoid'))(T)
    model = Model(input=[d_inputs,auxiliary_input], output=T)
    return model

def generator_containing_discriminator(generator, discriminator):
    T1 = generator([g_inputs, auxiliary_input])
    discriminator.trainable = False
    T2 = discriminator([T1,auxiliary_input])
    model = Model(input=[g_inputs, auxiliary_input], output=T2)
    return model

def combine_images(generated_images):
    num = generated_images.shape[0]
    width = int(math.sqrt(num))
    height = int(math.ceil(float(num)/width))
    shape = generated_images.shape[2:]
    image = np.zeros((height*shape[0], width*shape[1]), dtype=generated_images.dtype)
    for index, img in enumerate(generated_images):
        i = int(index/width)
        j = index % width
        image[i*shape[0]:(i+1)*shape[0], j*shape[1]:(j+1)*shape[1]] = img[0, :, :]
    return image


def train(BATCH_SIZE,y_prime):
    (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    X_train = (X_train.astype(np.float32) - 127.5)/127.5
    X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], 1) + X_train.shape[1:])
    discriminator = discriminator_model()
    generator = generator_model()
    discriminator_on_generator = generator_containing_discriminator(generator, discriminator)
    d_optim = SGD(lr=0.0005, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    g_optim = SGD(lr=0.0005, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer="SGD")
    discriminator_on_generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=g_optim)
    discriminator.trainable = True
    discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=d_optim)
    noise = np.zeros((BATCH_SIZE, 100))
    for epoch in range(100):
        print("Epoch is", epoch)
        print("Number of batches", int(X_train.shape[0]/BATCH_SIZE))
        for index in range(int(X_train.shape[0]/BATCH_SIZE)):
            for i in range(BATCH_SIZE):
                noise[i, :] = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 100)
            image_batch = X_train[index*BATCH_SIZE:(index+1)*BATCH_SIZE]
            y_batch = dense_to_one_hot(y_train[index*BATCH_SIZE:(index+1)*BATCH_SIZE])
            y_batch = np.concatenate((y_batch , y_prime))
            generated_images = generator.predict([noise,y_prime], verbose=0)
            if index % 20 == 0:
                image = combine_images(generated_images)
                image = image*127.5+127.5
                Image.fromarray(image.astype(np.uint8)).save(str(epoch)+"_"+str(index)+".png")
            X = np.concatenate((image_batch, generated_images))
            y = [1] * BATCH_SIZE + [0] * BATCH_SIZE
            d_loss = discriminator.train_on_batch([X,y_batch], y)
            print("batch %d d_loss : %f" % (index, d_loss))
            for i in range(BATCH_SIZE):
                noise[i, :] = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 100)
            discriminator.trainable = False
            g_loss = discriminator_on_generator.train_on_batch([noise,y_prime], [1] * BATCH_SIZE)
            discriminator.trainable = True
            print("batch %d g_loss : %f" % (index, g_loss))
            if index % 10 == 9:
                generator.save_weights('generator', True)
                discriminator.save_weights('discriminator', True)



train(100,y_p)
```

Comment: Have you tried checking if your layers are frozen well? This tends to bug a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for building Conditional GAN (CGAN) with Keras: https://github.com/hklchung/GAN-GenerativeAdversarialNetwork/tree/master/CGAN

After 5 epochs on MNIST I get this:
[MNIST CGAN output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEfSm.png)

and after 50 epochs on the CelebsA dataset:
[CelebA CGAN output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LUe6.jpg)

My experience is that if you don't see any good results after 20 epochs, something is wrong with your model and training it any longer won't improve your image quality.